# Move postfix maildir files from one mail server to another

Tags: email, postfix, courier, maildir

I have a new mail server configured as described in this howto:
http://howtoforge.com/virtual-users-domains-postfix-courier-mysql-squirrelmail-ubuntu-9.10

I also have an ancient mail server configured very similarly (using the same HOWTO, just for Fedora Core 6, if I recall correctly).

Earlier today I had to switch from the old server to the new one, and the old one is no longer online. However, after I had migrated everything and switched it all over, I discovered a bunch of undelivered mail in the queue. It got delivered to the local mailboxes on the old server, so now there are a bunch of messages on it that I'd like to move to the new server. The new server has already received new messages, so I need to merge the files together somehow.

For each user with an email of username@customer.com, there are files like this on both servers:

/home/vmail/customer.com/username/maildirsize
/home/vmail/customer.com/username/courierpop3dsizelist
/home/vmail/customer.com/username/new/1271481177.Vca01I6006bM580357.mailhost.mydomain.com

Can I simply copy the hundreds of files in the various **new** directories on the old server to the corresponding **new** directories on the new server? Will the **maildirsize** and **courierpop3dsizelist** files get updated automatically, or do I need to do something to update them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I jumped the gun asking this question. I went ahead and gave it a try with an unimportant account. I simply copied files from the old server **new** directory to the new server **new** directory, and my mail client downloaded them without any issues. Problem solved!